# Django: How to import model from same app?

Tags: python, django

I've an app called **lists**.

This has 3 main models: `List`, `ListItem` and `School`.

Every list could be related to 1 school, or this field could be empty.

But when I'm trying to update my model List to have a school field I'm getting:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'School' from 'lists.models' (D:\web_proyects\scolarte\lists\models.py)  
(scolarte)
```

Even thought both models are in the same `models.py` file.

I've tried:

```
from .models import School
```

And:

```
from lists.models import School
```

**lists/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from products.models import Product
from roles.models import User
from .models import School

# Create your models here.

class List(models.Model):
    LISTA_STATUS = (
        ('recibida_pagada', 'Recibida y pagada'),
        ('recibida_no_pagada', 'Recibida pero no pagada'),
        ('en_revision', 'En revision'),
        ('en_camino', 'En camino'),
        ('entregada', 'Entregada'),
        ('cancelada', 'Cancelada')
    )
    lista_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school = models.OneToOneField(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LISTA_STATUS, default='recibida_pagada')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class ListItem(models.Model):
    lista = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    step_two_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def sub_total(self):
        return int(self.product.price)



class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    address_reference = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    provincia = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    canton = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    parroquia = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Comment: have you tried getting rid of your import statement for school and just moving the school class before your list class in the code such that school is created and defined as a class in scope before you try to use it in list?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle that was it. Don't know if I delete the question or not. Maybe you can right an answer.

Comment: I have added it as an answer just for completeness of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to import `School` since its already in the same model. However you do need to define `School` first before you can then reference it in another class in the same model file. Update your model so `School` is defined before `List`

```py
from django.db import models
from products.models import Product
from roles.models import User
from .models import School

# Create your models here.
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    address_reference = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    provincia = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    canton = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    parroquia = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class List(models.Model):
    LISTA_STATUS = (
        ('recibida_pagada', 'Recibida y pagada'),
        ('recibida_no_pagada', 'Recibida pero no pagada'),
        ('en_revision', 'En revision'),
        ('en_camino', 'En camino'),
        ('entregada', 'Entregada'),
        ('cancelada', 'Cancelada')
    )
    lista_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school = models.OneToOneField(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LISTA_STATUS, default='recibida_pagada')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class ListItem(models.Model):
    lista = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    step_two_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def sub_total(self):
        return int(self.product.price)
```

Comment: Could you verify if the OnetoOne relationship is the right one for this case? More details in the original question. Ty, Sir.